# Indentation error in python, replit with conditional statements

Tags: python, indentation

```py
print('''
 __      _            
 / _|    (_)           
| |_ __ _ _ _ __ _   _ 
|  _/ _` | | '__| | | |
| || (_| | | |  | |_| |
|_| \__,_|_|_|   \__, |
                  __/ |
                 |___/ 
''')
print("Welcome to fairyland! Your mission is to find the cmal pixie dust which will give the fairies their power back and at the end you can get a surprise!")

print("Lets start the game!")

reply1 = input("You're in a dazziling forest and you see two paths there which one your choosing? left or right ").lower
if reply1 == "left":
   reply2 = input("You meet a unicorn, she gives you a map. type Y for to take it or type N to not take it").lower
  if reply2 == "y":
    reply3 = input("You see a jar with some weird glittery looking dust inside, Type "yes" to pick and open the jar or Type "no" to not pickup the jar")
  else:
  print("IT WAS THE PIXIE DUST! Now thw witches took it away, Game Over")
else:
  print("You got caught by the wicked witches, Game Over")
```

What's causing this error?

```
File "main.py", line 18
    if reply2 == "y":
                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and to make a [mre].

Comment: BTW, you forgot to call `.lower`. It should be `.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space before this line:

> ```
> reply2 = input("You meet a unicorn, she gives you a map. type Y for to take it or type N to not take it").lower
> ```

And it appears you're missing an indent here:

> ```
> print("IT WAS THE PIXIE DUST! Now thw witches took it away, Game Over")
> ```